# Why my app is taking this class as uninitialized constant Booking::String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am using mongodb through mongoid gem in rails. I am new to it. I've created a model in this which is following:

```
class Booking
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  embeds_many :extras
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :extras

  field :bedroom, type: Integer
  field :bathroom, type: String
  field :frequency, type: String
  field :extras, type: String
  field :zipcode, type: Integer
  field :date, type: String
  field :time, type: String
  field :date_timestamp, type: Time
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :address, type: String
  field :apartment, type: Strng
  field :phone, type: String
  field :alt_phone, type: String
  field :key_info, type: Integer
  field :key_details, type: String
  field :coupon_code, type: String
  field :gift_card_code, type: String
  field :gift_card_amount, type: Float
  field :referral_amount, type: Float
  field :final_amount, type: Float
  field :created_at, type: Time
  field :updated_at, type: Time
end
```

And whenever I access it index page having code

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bookings = Booking.all
  end
end
```

It returns me `uninitialized constant Booking::Strng` error. I've spend hour in finding out its reason. Can anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: Voting to close this because it's a simple typographical error: `Strng` instead of `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `String` is spelled with an `i` :)  See your `:apartment` line.

Btw, I'll add that this is so common in programming, never trust your eyes, all I did here was copied the string from the error and Cmd+F searched for it in this page (your code).

Comment: Oh shit really man! Thank you very much. I stuck into the name of the error for hours and wasted a lot of my time. Really thank you.